# Get the event of a Logon failed for a local account in the Member server in a Domain Controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, audit-logging, domaincontroller

I am trying to hit a member server in an AD domain network with a local account and a wrong password. The logon failure event is logged in the Member server and not in the Domain Controller. But when I am hitting with a domain account the Domain Controller has a log in it. I want the same to be reflected with local accounts too. Is there any way??

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

When you use a domain account, the member server has to verify the credentials with the domain controller, and the DC decides whether the authentication is successful. That's why you see the event there.

But the same is not true with local accounts. The member server authenticates the credentials itself, without help from the domain controller. So the DC has no idea the authentication even happened.

Comment: But When i hit the same member server with a local account from within an another member server or DC , the events are logged in to DC. The same is not happening if i am hitting from the outside

Comment: When you test, are you specifying the computer name with the username? (like `COMPUTERNAME\username`) If not, it's probably trying to authenticate on the domain because it doesn't know if it's a domain account or a local account. After failing the domain authentication, it tries local authentication.

Comment: The username i tried to hit is **TEST** ,**USR1**  and i didn't mention any domain. The event is logged in the DC saying credential validation failed. But, when i hit from other than member servers , there is no log in the DC (DC showing up only for users specified with domain like `test@corp.local` )

Comment: Right. So because you didn't mention any domain, it doesn't know if it's a domain or a local account, so it will try both. Even if you give it the right password, I suspect you would still see a failure on the DC. If you specify that it's a local account (by using `COMPUTERNAME\username`), then you will probably see nothing at all on the DC.